# How to get the thread which has just hit breakpoint when the debuger receive SIGTRAP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging

I'm not using gdb, I'm developing a debuger like gdb on linux.

I can receive SIGTRAP in my debugger process, but I don't know how to get the right thread which hit the breakpoint in target process.

First I guess I should use ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, ...) to get a siginfo_t, but there seems no attribute in siginfo_t can tell me the thread id.

Then I think maybe I can get something from the signal, and match the breakpoint information in debugger, so I downloaded gdb source code (7.10), but OMG it's too large, I can't get the relevant functions.

so I'm here now, could someone help me?

Comment: IMHO the mechanism on Linux is to set a memory breakpoint. Any thread could access that address and thus trigger the breakpoint. Therefore, the question is: how would that information be relevant? On Windows for example, the debugger injects a new thread which then runs on an `int 3` instruction. In a similar fashion, it's useless to find out more about this thread, because you can't do anything about it.

Comment: Maybe I didn't throw my question clearly enough, I want to implement a similar feature in my new debuger: the non-stop mode in gdb (since v7.10).<br />"For some multi-threaded targets, GDB supports an optional mode of operation in which you can examine stopped program threads in the debugger while other threads continue to execute freely. This minimizes intrusion when debugging live systems, such as programs where some threads have real-time constraints or must continue to respond to external events. This is referred to as non-stop mode."

Comment: Maybe I misread or I could just not believe that you're writing your own debugger :-) On WIndows, there are 2 concepts of stopping a thread: suspending and freezing. When the debugger breaks, all threads are suspended. When you hit "continue", threads are un-suspended again. If you don't want some threads to continue, you could freeze those threads. AFAIK, such a possibility must be provided by the OS, because otherwise it would simply schedule the threads to run.